# Notes about evaluating double and triple integrals

Tags: integration, reference-request, multivariable-calculus

I'm searching notes and exercises about multiple integrals to calculate volume of functions, but the information I find in internet is very bad. Can someone recommend me a book, pdf, videos, website... whatever to learn about this?

The exercise type I have to learn to do are similar to the following:

> Calculate the volume inside these equations: $x^2+y^2=4, z=0, x+y+z=4$.

Comment: the two equations you wrote represent a cylinder and a plane. You need at least one more surface to have an "inside" to measure its volume.

Comment: I have a cilinder and two planes (z=0, x+y+z=4) I solved that problem thanks to the Paul's Notes and the solution is 16π :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consult **Paul's Online Notes**, a tutorial-style site that addresses topics ranging from trig to Single- and multivariable calculus, and differential equations. In particular see [Calculus III](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/CalcIII.aspx) and click on multiple integrals from the menu on the left.

You might also want to check out the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/multivariable-calculus) for videos/tutorials of topics in multivariable calculus. Just scan the menu to the left of the linked webpage for particular topics to brush up on.

Comment: I'm reading Paul's Online Notes and they're are excelent

Comment: Nice feedback! =1

Answer (score 3):

When I took both Calc 2 and Calc 3, I used [PatrickJMT](http://patrickjmt.com/topic/calculus/) a lot.  Pauls Online Notes are also great, as mentioned by amWhy.  There are pretty much an infinite number of sites or textbooks, or youtube videos that you can find this information

Answer (score 1):

Consider watching [these video lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/video-lectures/) on MIT OCW for multivariable calculus, specifically lecture 16.

Also, [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlEOdQgFC14) by DrChrisTisdell quickly addresses the specific type of question about which you are interested.